Ingestion av big data sets in azure for datawarehouse
I am about to setup a new data plattform on microsoft azure.
I will have mutiple data sources of a different types and size.
I would like to have input of available options when ingesting the data into azure data lake.
For now when can assume that all data sources will be of database types.
Some will be small but at least two will be of significant size (10M records a day created continously). Once the data is ingested into azure data lake it will be processed for analytics in azure.
I am considering different options to use for ingesting the data where Azure Data Factory/dataflow is the main candidate currently.
I also need to decide the format for landing the data in Azure data lake. Options are azure sql db (there are different options here?) or parquet files or a mix.
I am also open to concider databricks but I have little experience in that product.
Any feedback or input would be very much appriciated.

Azure Data Factory is a good option for ingesting data into Azure Data Lake Storage. Data can be ingested using Azure Data Factory's more than 90 built-in connectors, including connectors for Azure native services, Oracle, SAP, and more. For larger datasets, network latency can be a problem, and Azure ExpressRoute or Azure Import/Export service can be used to transfer data. Once the data is ingested into Azure Data Lake Storage, it can be stored as Parquet files, which are optimized for read-heavy analytics pipelines. Azure Synapse Analytics is a good choice for storing prepared results.
